# Run other curl when the other curl call is already in progress in PHP

Tags: php, curl, asynchronous, parallel-processing, external

I have to call external script in which i make a first call with CURL to get data which takes about 2-3 minutes, Now during this time i need to make other external call with CURL to get the progress of the first call. But issue is my next call wait till the reply of first CURL comes. I also checked curl_multi but that is also not helping me as i want to make many calls when the first call is in progress. So anyone can help me to solve it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that, there is no need to make second call to track the CURL progress. You can achieve the same by using CURL option `CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION` with a callback function.

The call back method takes 5 arguments:

1. cURL resource
2. Total number of bytes expected to be downloaded
3. Number of bytes downloaded so far
4. Total number of bytes expected to be uploaded
5. Number of bytes uploaded so far

In the callback method you can calculate the percentage downloaded/uploaded. An example is given below:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://stackoverflow.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, 'progress');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

function progress($resource,$download_size, $downloaded, $upload_size, $uploaded)
{
    if($download_size > 0)
        echo $downloaded / $download_size  * 100 . "%\n";
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this is something diff. this is not curl progress i want , I want is the first cal makes calculation for something for which i need the percentage to display for that i surely need to make a second call. So is there any way i can do it?

Comment: Hi @Dileep I tried the approach you asked to, But now i got into similar type of issue. In here i stored progress in the session and By other ajax call i tried to fetch it, But the other ajax call Hangs(wait) till the whole Curl call ends. Any solution for this?

Comment: Hi @Savan ajax based progress monitoring explained here http://www.binarytides.com/ajax-based-streaming-without-polling/. There is only one request sent and chunked output to show the request progress. Your callback method will produce chunked output in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this - please see the following links, they explain how to do this using curl_multi_init: [php.net curl_multi_init](http://arguments.callee.info/2010/02/21/multiple-curl-requests-with-php/) and [http://arguments.callee.info/2010/02/21/multiple-curl-requests-with-php/](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php)

Comment: You are right they show but this is diff. in my case. In here they add all the request together and the call curl. But in my case i have to call the first curl with ajax which takes time and now during this i have to call other curl with ajax which can get response instant and should not wait for first call to finish. So in my case there is 2 diff. call is needed in real that is the issue.

Comment: So you mean to say there is no other way to do in php?

Comment: I think you are looking for multiple thread support where in the first thread to make curl request and the second one will check the status (the first thread completed or not). correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: In second one i call another CURL (external call) which gives me progress in percentage to be printed. This call i do each 2 seconds to get the progress.